# Import a .dll Library in VScode

Tags: visual-c++, dll, dllimport

I want to use a library in Visual C++.
I downloaded a folder called "Microsoft Visual C++"
In this folder I have 2 folders :

1. A file called "Definition Files" which contains .h files, a .dll files and a .lib files.
2. A file called "Example VC++" .cpp files and other files

The definitions file contain function I want to use in a project. I want to know how to link this library I downloaded to my C++ project in Visual Studio.
Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Sacha DULOUT

I try to include the definition file .h in my main.cpp file and I tried to configure my .json file to link the .lib and .dll to my project.